# The Items.Count of a FormView returns null on Insert view

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have a FormView that should return 0, 1 or 2 rows. When the FormView current view is ReadOnly (on PageLoad) or Edit (on postBack), the DataItemCount is correct. However in the Insert view (on postBack)  the number of DataItemCount is always 0. How can I keep the correct number of rows in the Insert view (on postBack)?

Content Page

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView3" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
    OnDatabound="FormView3_DataBound"
    runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="IDeditorLanguage"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_languages">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        html stuff
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        html stuff
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server"
            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server"
            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');"/>
        <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-default" ID="NewButton"
            runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
            CommandName="New" Text="New" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:label runat="server" ID="languagesNumer"></asp:label>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void FormView3_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (FormView3.DataItemCount == 0)
    {
        languagesNumer.Text = "The number is 0";
    }
    else if (FormView3.DataItemCount == 1)
    {
        languagesNumer.Text = "The number is 1";
    }
    else if (FormView3.DataItemCount == 2)
    {
        languagesNumer.Text = "The number is 2";
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

This is how I solved the problem:

```
  protected void FormView3_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  


 if (FormView3.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
        {
            numberLanguages = FormView3.DataItemCount;
        }


    if (numberLanguages == 0)
    {
        languagesNumer.Text = "The number is 0";
    }
    else if (numberLanguages == 1)
    {
        languagesNumer.Text = "The number is 1";
    }
    else if (numberLanguages == 2)
    {
        languagesNumer.Text = "The number is 2";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong, that's just the way it is. Since an insert item is just a blank slate, there is no sense in paging from one to another, whereas any item may be edited, so paging between them is necessary. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In fact I solved the problem in the update above. I assigned the DataItemCount to a variable in the ReadOnly view.

Comment: Ok, just note that if you don't return to ReadOnly mode every time after you insert, you may not have an accurate count.

Comment: In my case the user must return to the ReadOnly view after each insert which means that the above code works perfectly well. Thank you for the note. Well appreciated.